# mat-progress-bar updating in real time

Tags: angular, angular-material

Updated only after page reload. Is it possible to update the progress bar in real time?

```
<mat-progress-bar
  *ngIf="row.stage === 'importing_in_progress'"
  class="exchange-files__progress-bar"
  mode="determinate"
  [value]="row.progress"
></mat-progress-bar>
```

Comment: Real time from where? As long as you update variable row.progress with a value 0 - 100 somewhere the component will update. You could call an API on a timer or implment signalR to push from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the value you pass to the `[value]` attribute is updated in a way so angular change detection will pick it up. One way is to use an observable

```
const progress = of([1,3,4]).pipe(delay(1000));
```

and pass it to `mat-progress-bar` with the `async` pipe.

```
<mat-progress-bar
 ...
 [value]="progress | async"
></mat-progress-bar>
```

This should make the progress bar update in real-time.